# ASP.NET MVC 2 Areas and AfterBuildCompiler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, areas

I am just trying out Areas in ASP.NET MVC 2 and I've hit a small issue.

I've added the appropriate lines to my project file:

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="AfterBuildCompiler">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <AreasManifestDir>$(ProjectDir)\..\Manifests</AreasManifestDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <CreateAreaManifest AreaName="$(AssemblyName)" AreaType="Child" AreaPath="$(ProjectDir)" ManifestPath="$(AreasManifestDir)" ContentFiles="@(Content)" />
  </Target>
```

But the problem I have is that I get the following error:

The target "AfterBuildCompiler" does not exist in the project.

I think I'm missing something obvious - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i got that error it was because the Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build.dll was missing in C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies

Don't know if it's the only problem though.

Comment: Well, it came with VS2010 i think. I didn't explore Areas with separate projects further since they put it in Futures so i went with Area folders instead.